# Why am I getting error on TryGetSettings when using postprocessing v2 ? And how can I fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, post-processing

In the editor on my Camera I added two components : Post Process Layer and Post Process Volume
On the first component the layer I changed the Layer to a layer I added PostProcessing
On the second component I set the Is Global to true and added one effect for now Depth Of Field

Now I want to change and set values to the Depth Of Field Focal Length via a script.
So I created a new script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing;

public class PostprocessingEffects : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PostProcessVolume postProcessVolume;
    private DepthOfField depthOfField;

    void Start()
    {
        postProcessVolume = GetComponent<PostProcessVolume>();
        postProcessVolume.profile.TryGetSettings(out PostProcessEffectSettings depthOfFieldSettings);

        depthOfField.focalLength.value = 1f;
    }
}
```

I'm getting error on the line :

```
postProcessVolume.profile.TryGetSettings(out depthOfField);
```

On the TryGetSettings and the error is :

The type 'PostprocessingEffects' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'PostProcessProfile.TryGetSettings(out T)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'PostprocessingEffects' to 'UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing.PostProcessEffectSettings'.

Tried also :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.PostProcessing;

public class PostprocessingEffects : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PostProcessVolume postProcessVolume;
    private DepthOfField depthOfField;

    void Start()
    {
        postProcessVolume = GetComponent<PostProcessVolume>();
        postProcessVolume.profile.TryGetSettings(out DepthOfField depthOfField);

        depthOfField.focalLength.value = 1f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're using incorrect type.

`TryGetSettings` cannot take type of `PostprocessingEffects`
I believe you want `DepthOfField` try:

```
postProcessVolume.profile.TryGetSettings(out DepthOfField depthOfField);
```

of if you have your variable already defined:

```
private DepthOfField depthOfField;
postProcessVolume.profile.TryGetSettings(out depthOfField);
```

Also make sure you have depth of field effect attached to Postprocess Volume in inspector

Comment: This is working changing to the PostProcessEffectSettings depthOfFieldSettings but a bit strange because I took the sample code from this tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jg2I2odw51M and on minute 6:53 he is using the same as in my code and he didn't get any errors.

Comment: You might be using different versions of unity where API looked a bit differently or class names were renamed. Anyway, if it solves the issue, please accept the answer :)

Comment: And now I'm getting null on the depthOfField : depthOfField.focalLength.value = 1f; in the video tutorial he using bloom effect but not getting null.

Comment: If it's null that means there is no such effect attached to the Postprocess Volume. If you navigate through the inspector, find Postprocess Volume, add DepthOfField effect and by the way, I suppose the class name might be different, in video he used Bloom and you need DepthOfField. Not PostProcessEffect or Settings. I'll update answer

Comment: I edited my question the type of the depthOfField now is DepthOfField and in the camera in the editor I added two components one is the postprocessing layer and the other is post processing volume and then added the depthoffield effect I can change the focal length value in the editor from 1 to 300 and it will change the view to blurry but  now I want to change it using the script.

Comment: I'm using the postprocessing version 2.3.0 from the package manager in the editor.  and my editor version is 2019.2.5f1

Comment: I tried your updated answer but still it's not changing the value of the focal length.

Comment: In the current version of your code, depthOfField is never assigned. Try using `postProcessVolume.profile.TryGetSettings(out depthOfField)` and forget the `PostProcessEffectSettings `, I don't think you need it

Comment: I tried the bottom example in your question. Works fine to me. Upon entering playmode, focal length is set to 1. Did you attach the script to correct game object? What errors are you getting with it?